# Function doesn't display the correct solution in android app, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

The program should take in a length, width, and depth measurement from the user and then display how many gallons of water the tank can hold.  However, when I do something like "12,12,14" for the measurements, it gives me some ridiculously large number instead of something around 15 gallons.  Here is the main activity:

```
package com.example.aquariumconverter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText gallonText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    String strlen = String.valueOf(R.id.editText2);
    String strwid = String.valueOf(R.id.editText3);
    String strdep = String.valueOf(R.id.editText4);
    double length = Double.parseDouble(strlen);
    double width = Double.parseDouble(strwid);
    double depth = Double.parseDouble(strdep);

    RectangularTank recTank = new RectangularTank(length,width,depth);
    final String strConvertedToGallons = recTank.convertToGallons(length,width,depth);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gallonText.setText(strConvertedToGallons);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And here is the rectangulartank class:

```
package com.example.aquariumconverter;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class RectangularTank{

public RectangularTank(double length, double width, double depth) {
    super();
    init(length, width, depth);
}

 private void init(double length, double width, double depth)
 {
     convertToGallons(length, width, depth);

 }

public String convertToGallons(double length, double width, double depth)
{
    double feetLength = length / 12.0;
    double feetWidth = width / 12.0;
    double feetDepth = depth / 12.0;
    double gallonAmount = feetLength * feetWidth * feetDepth * 7.47;
    String strGallonAmount = String.valueOf(gallonAmount);
    return strGallonAmount;
}



}
```

Here is an updated version of the Main activity after some suggestions:

```
package com.example.aquariumconverter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText gallonText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText editText2Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);    
    EditText editText3Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);    
    EditText editText4Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    double length, width, depth;
    try {
        length = Double.valueOf(editText2Text.getText().toString());
        width = Double.valueOf(editText3Text.getText().toString());
        depth = Double.valueOf(editText4Text.getText().toString());
    }  catch (NumberFormatException e){
        length=0;
        width=0;
        depth=0;
    }

    RectangularTank recTank = new RectangularTank(length,width,depth);
    final String strConvertedToGallons = recTank.convertToGallons(length,width,depth);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gallonText.setText(strConvertedToGallons);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Width"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="Depth"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="Rectangular Tank"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Length"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Convert" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `feetLength * feetWidth * feetDepth * 7.47;`  12x12x14x7.47 = 15059.52.  Where did you get the 7.47 magic number from?  I guess it's gallons per cubic foot?

Comment: feetLength wouldn't be 12, it would be 1, because it's divided by 12 and converted to feet.  what it should equal, is just under 15 gallons.  Here is the link I got the formula for converting to gallons from:

http://www.dep.state.pa.us/dep/deputate/waterops/redesign/calculators/volcalchtm.htm

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line of ConvertToGallons.  Run your app.  Do the arguments have the values you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
String strlen = String.valueOf(R.id.editText2);
```

This is **not** the **correct** way to get the text from `EditText`

You need to initilize the `EditText` then you need to get the text from the `EditText` by this `editText2Text.getText().toString().trim()`

```
EditText editText2Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);    
EditText editText3Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);    
EditText editText4Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

String strlen = editText2Text.getText().toString().trim();
String strwid = editText3Text.getText().toString().trim();
String strdep = editText4Text.getText().toString().trim();
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
    try{
          length = Double.parseDouble(editText2Text.getText().toString());
          width = Double.parseDouble(editText3Text.getText().toString());
          depth = Double.parseDouble(editText4Text.getText().toString());
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        length=0;
        width=0;
        depth=0;
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have found out the problem.. You have not got the text from edittext on button click. Try to get it in button click. It will work..

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
try{
              length = Double.parseDouble(editText2Text.getText().toString());
              width = Double.parseDouble(editText3Text.getText().toString());
              depth = Double.parseDouble(editText4Text.getText().toString());
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
            length=0;
            width=0;
            depth=0;
        }

     RectangularTank recTank = new RectangularTank(length,width,depth);
    final String strConvertedToGallons = recTank.convertToGallons(length,width,depth);

            gallonText.setText(strConvertedToGallons);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok, I tried editing the code the way you suggested, but then it crashed so I had to add a try catch exception for when the length, width, or depth box carries an empty string.  I think I have done that correctly, but now when I hit the convert button after inputting 12,12,24 it just keeps saying the answer is 0.0.  I have added an updated version of the file to the post.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @criscodisco it seems all correct. print `length` in logcat value is comming or not

Comment: @criscodisco and also you can try my edit use  `Double.parseDouble("")`

Comment: The length appears to be 0.  However, when I log the editText2Text, it is 12.  So I'm not really sure why length isn't taking in that value.

Comment: Also made the change to Double.parseDouble("") as well.

Comment: @criscodisco is there any errors?. and also add this line in your catch `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: @criscodisco codes all working correctly i checked it. i think your getting `NumberFormatException` so that values are **0** . check it clearly. and also post what your entered in three edittext. If your edittext is **empty** or any other **string like a,b,c** it will give error.

Comment: I have been putting 12 for length, 12 for width, and 24 for depth.  I don't see why it would be giving me the NumberFormatException if I am typing numbers into all three boxes.  Is it possible that the problem lies with my xml?

Comment: @criscodisco i am getting **14.94** for the same value you given. is there any space your giving.

Comment: No, no spaces.

There are some yellow errors in the stack trace:

12-05 07:10:31.201: W/System.err(1863): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
12-05 07:10:31.201: W/System.err(1863):  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
12-05 07:10:31.201: W/System.err(1863):  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
12-05 07:10:31.201: W/System.err(1863):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)


Also, I am going to post my xml file in case there is something wrong there.

Comment: @criscodisco i think one of the edit text value is empty so that error.

Comment: @criscodisco only reason your parsing empty string to double that error will come.

Comment: I have uploaded an image of what it looks like after i hit the convert button.  This is pretty frustrating, I don't understand why it works fine for you.

Comment: Yes!  It works!  And I see why that works too, I don't know why it didn't occur to me to put it all in there.  It makes sense though.  Thank you very much!